# Semaforo con pulsos en python

Tags: python, python-3.7

El enunciado es el siguiente:

El semáforo tiene una entrada: el pulsador

El pulsador genera 2 posibles valores:
0 si no está pulsado
1 cuando está pulsado

Mientras el pulsador está en 0,el semáforo permanece en el mismo
estado (con uno de los tres leds encendido)

Cuando el pulsador está en 1, .el semáforo pasa al siguiente estado:
de rojo a amarillo
de amarillo a verde
de verde a rojo

```
El codigo funciona solo que no se corta el ciclo for al ingresar un caracter por teclado

    from os import system
    vector = ["\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O",
    "\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;31m"+"O",
    "\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;33m"+"O"]
    i=0
    a=0
    valor = False
    while a==0:
        for i in range(3):
            pulso = input()
            system ("cls")
            if pulso == "":
                print(vector[i])
            else:
                if pulso == "a":
                    valor = True
        if pulso == "":
            i = 0
        if valor == True:
            break
```

Comment: si no ingresas nada, y das enter, entras en un ciclo infinito?

Comment: Cada vez que das enter el semaforo va cambiando de color, el problema esta en que cuando ingresamos cualquier otra cosa que no sea un enter el semaforo no termina como deberia y es un problema en el ciclo for

Comment: Qué es lo que debería pasar cuando aprietas otra cosa que no sea enter?

Comment: Se deberia finalizar el ciclo while

Answer (score 0):

Tu finalización no funciona porque no estás rompiendo el bucle `for` al encontrar lo condición, por lo que aunque uses el break, no ha llegado aún a esa parte del código, pues lo hace hasta terminar el ciclo `for`. Por lo que solo tienes que añadir un `break` cuando encuentres esa condición para que salga de ese bucle

```
vector = ["\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O",
"\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;31m"+"O",
"\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;33m"+"O"]
i=0
a=0
valor = False
while a==0:
    for i in range(3):
        pulso = input()
        if pulso == "":
            print(vector[i])
        else:
            if pulso == "a":
                valor = True
                break
    if valor:
        break
```

De esta funciona tu código se corta cuando presionas la tecla `a`.

Si quieres que sea con cualquier otra tecla que no sea `enter` cambia

```
else:
    if pulso == "a":
        valor = True
        break
```

por

```
else:
   valor = True
   break
```

También si quieres tener más limpio tu código puede quedar de la siguiente forma

```
vector = ["\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O",
"\x1b[1;33m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;31m"+"O",
"\x1b[1;32m"+"O"" " "\x1b[1;31m"+"O"" ""\x1b[1;33m"+"O"]
i=0
valor = False
while not valor:
    pulso = input()
    if pulso == "":
        print(vector[i])
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
    else:
        valor = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
sema = 0
while True:
    if input("?"):
        sema = (sema + 1) % 3
    print("VAR"[sema])
```

Si ingresas cualquier cosa, el semáforo cicla. Si sólo das Enter, el semáforo sigue igual.

La expresión `(sema + 1) % 3` calcula el resto del contador respecto a 3. Con eso `sema` cicla 0,1 y 2.

Usamo `sema` como indice para acceder a la representación visual del semáforo. En este caso, opte por "V", "A" y "R", pero puedes también usar una lista con cadenas más complejas.

#### Demo

El código produce:

```
?
V
?x
A
?x
R
?x
V
?
V
?
V
?
```